# Ошибка в запросе SQL "1064"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla, cms

Есть сайт на джумле и есть магазин на JoomShoping переходя по ссылке в категорию вылазит вот такая ошибка "1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1" я понимаю что ошибка в линии 1 но я не могу отследить где ошибка возникает в каком именно запросе и в каком файле, так как сайт собирали до меня, такая же ошибка и с плагином магазина Virtuemart. Может кто-то сталкивался с данной проблемой и может подсказать как найти "поломаный" запрос.?

Comment: Не силен в этой цмс, но подозреваю что есть одна точка входа в SQL, включите там логирование и посмотрите какой именно запрос ломает.

Comment: *я понимаю что ошибка в линии 1* Нет. Это сообщение об ошибке самого MySQL. Это - ошибка парсинга переданного серверу текста запроса, в тексте имеется синтаксическая ошибка. А процитированный фрагмент - это собственно та точка, в которой возникла проблема парсинга. А начать надо, я думаю, с получения из лога полного текста запроса.

Comment: А как получить этот самый лог ошибок mqsql? Есть лог ошибок но там только ошибки php  которые не имеют отношения к данной проблеме.

Comment: Спасибо кто отклюикнулся проблему нашел в одном из плагинов не хотел обрабатываться знак амперсанта.